# (Done)Req to Reopen How to Deal With Legacy Software and Split Opnion

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

The question [How to deal with legacy software and split opinion](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/133658/how-to-deal-with-legacy-software-and-split-opinion) only needs one more open vote to be reopened. Given that the reason it was closed was "Because ask a software question on a software engineering site" can we go ahead and reopen this.

There are specific right answers to dealing with this soft of disagreement in the office so I don't think the question is actually too broad. It's pretty clear that software engineering is the context of the question.

Questions about the field of software engineering are as welcome as questions about any other industry on The Workplace after all.

Answer (score -2):

Casted the final vote, and the post is now open again.